# How to check if a column name is contained in an array in a different column and extract only those rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Question is a bit of a mouthful but here's what I'm working with:

I have a dataframe like this:

| CO2 | INVALIDS |
| --- | --- |
| 35.3 | [SO2] |
| 2.5 | [CO2, SO2, NO2] |

(Index is in `DatetimeIndex` format but it's inconvenient to show using GitHub table markdown format)

Essentially, I would like to extract those rows in which (in this case) 'CO2' is contained in 'INVALIDS' column.

So here I'd extract the second row and I'd be left with:

| CO2 | INVALIDS |
| --- | --- |
| 2.5 | [CO2, SO2, NO2] |

I tried doing it by using this approach:

```
df.loc[df.columns[~df.columns.isin(['INVALIDS'])][0] in df['INVALIDS']]
```

However, this returns a list of `True` / `False` values which gives the following exception:

```
'False: boolean label can not be used without a boolean index'
```

I think I could do this with `iterrows` approach but surely there's a better (vectorized) way.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the output of `type(df["INVALIDS"].iloc[0])`?

Comment: @Erfan It is `list`. (I accidentally copied the wrong error but I edited it now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vectorized solution would be possible with `Series.explode` and using the index of the booleans with `.loc`:

```
m = df["INVALIDS"].explode().eq("CO2")
df.loc[m[m].index]
```

```
   CO2         INVALIDS
1  2.5  [CO2, SO2, NO2]
```

---

Edit to match the column names:

```
m = df["INVALIDS"].explode().isin(df.columns)
df.loc[m[m].index]
```

```
   CO2         INVALIDS
1  2.5  [CO2, SO2, NO2]
```

Comment: If you test it however, you'll see that most of the time, `explode` is much slower than a list comprehension as it needs to recreate a full dataframe internally. Only use `explode` when you need an exploded DataFrame, not to create an intermediate for indexing.

Comment: I highly doubt that, since I helped working on `explode` internally. It is almost fully written in C and Cython. Can you give me an example where list comprehension is faster? @mozway

Comment: @Erfan for instance `S = set(df.columns) ; df[[bool(S.intersection(l)) for l in df['INVALIDS']]]` here depending on the input size. I've timed it many times on other examples and found `explode` frequently slower. Maybe I am unaware of recent `explode` improvement?

Answer (score 1):

As you have lists, you must loop. Use a list comprehension with `any` for boolean indexing:

```
out = df[[any('CO2' in x for x in l) for l in df['INVALIDS']]]
```

output:

```
   CO2         INVALIDS
1  2.5  [CO2, SO2, NO2]
```

Comment: Why do you need  `any('CO2' in x for x in l)`?

Comment: @Vitalizzare to find is any value is CO2, but give OP's precisions a better example would be: `S = set(df.columns) ; df[[bool(S.intersection(l)) for l in df['INVALIDS']]]` to match against the columns

Comment: Isn't `'CO2' in l` enough?